# Can't assign req.body.data to a variable

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, express

I can see that `req.body.data.resource` is a string:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3t0x.png

But when I try to assign it to a variable, the variable is undefined
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLOcl.png

The code:

```
router.post("/resource", async(req, res) => {
  const resourceName: string = req.body.data.resource_name
  const resourceValue: string = req.body.data.resource
  const resource: Resource  = {resource: resourceValue, resource_name: resourceName}
  const result = await writeResource(resource)
  res.send(result)
})
```

Resource is an interface I defined and exported

```
export interface Resource {
    resource: string,
    resource_name: string
}
```

Assigning `req.body.data.resource` to a variable. Was not expecting the variable to be undefined even though req.body.data.resource is not undefined

Comment: What's `writeResource`? show the code